# Dynamic forms with django

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue that I can't get around with, even though I tried a lot of solutions on SO and other sites, but they don't work for the dynamics I need (a lot is hard coded).

The thing is, I have a file with a dictionary in it, which can be updated when more files are added to that "framework". It is a custom code project, that I am building a web interface for.

So here is an example of that dictionary:

```
filespatterns = {
    "file1": "Open File1",
    "file2": "Open File2",
}
```

Basically the same way Django works with the installed apps, you create the file with the classes and functions in it that you want it to work with. And through the web interface you can send commands to them.

Now for the problem:

I have Django set up that it reads that dictionary and creates a pulldown menu on the webinterface with no problem whatsoever, and I have no problem creating the forms for each of the interfaces based on the files. But considering the amount of forms needed is variable (and well, who would want a web interface with hundreds of forms stacked on top of eachother when such a thing grows). How could I hide all the forms except for the one selected in the pulldown menu?

Is there a way to do that in forms.py, or should I do that directly into the template? I am still learning Django, and it is quite an extensive framework that I can't see the forest anymore due to all the trees :)

Thanks in advance all.

Edit: Adding some code, that does nothing but show the menu (as it should):

```
forms.py:

from django import forms
import front.commands as commands

class CommandForm(forms.Form):
    order_select = commands.framework.items()
    command = forms.ChoiceField(choices=order_select, label="Select Command", widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'Hide()'}))
```

This shows the available files in the "framework" I am building nicely in a pull down menu. As well as calling to a javascript function I am working with right now trying to hide all the forms on the page except for the one selected in the pulldown menu.

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Hide()
        {
            val = document.getElementsByName('command');
            forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
                for(f in forms)
                    {
                        document.forms[0].style.display = 'none';
                    }                       
            document.getElementsByName(val).style.display='block';
        } 
</script>
```

So far it is partially working.

Each form on the page gets the same name as is the value in the dropdown menu, as specified in the dictionary.

If I can get the javascript working fully, I am already happy, but I am wondering if there is a "Django Way" of doing this.

**SOLUTION:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Hide()
        {
        val = document.getElementsByName('command');
        forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
                for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++)
                {
                    document.forms[i].style.display = 'none';
                }                       
        document.forms[val[0].value].style.display='block';
    } 
</script>
```

I found a solution in javascript. This works perfectly in combination with the above code.

However, I still wonder if there is a Django way to do this, or if this is the only way to do it.

Comment: This is far too vague to answer. Why would the forms be stacked on top of each other? What do you want the menu to do? Show some code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added code to the question. As I keep on trying stuff to make it work. But what I need it to do is hide all the forms except for the one selected in the dropdown menu.

Comment: the document.forms[0].style.display is just a test for one of the forms. Because I got errors in my browser console :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer when it comes to doing it with Javascript, which is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Hide()
        {
        val = document.getElementsByName('command');
        forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
                for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++)
                {
                    document.forms[i].style.display = 'none';
                }                       
        document.forms[val[0].value].style.display='block';
    } 
</script>
```

What this does is get the select box (in this case with the name 'command').
After that it gets all the forms on the page, and hides them one by one by looping through the entire list of forms.
Then it uses the value of the selected form from the dropbox, and displays only that one.